# facebook video thumbnail image URLs?

Tags: facebook, video, thumbnails

For example, this is the url to a facebook video thumbnail:
http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/vthumb-ak-sf2p/v10822/239/59/505867356/t505867356_382364037356_272.jpg

There are quite a few obfuscation identifiers in there which prevent me from doing something like taking a video id and making a thumbnail link.

The reason I'd like the thumbnail is to be able to populate a 'navigator' band with the various videos from the app.

Anyway, anyone know of a way to get the video thumbnail url?

Answer (score 0):

find your video id, and this the url of thumbnail https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture

Comment: only small version (128x128), how can i get larger thumbnail version ?

Comment: The url https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture works for some of the ID's while for others, it doesn't. Like for video

https://www.facebook.com/RobertScoble/videos/10153768628394655
this link http://graph.facebook.com/10153768628394655 gives error 100

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "CxtkKmhwbWy"
   }
}

Comment: From what I can tell, this only works for pages, not users. Users have to authenticate and give permission for a site to use this method. Which is why it doesn't always work...